# NDepend NDepend_TfvcTemplate.12.EN.xaml - error to build

Tags: xaml, tfs, build-process, ndepend

today I followed the NDepend documentation to run a build using the build process template, I have added the assemblies and used the deploy tool provided.

But when I put it to run it fails:

```
 Exception Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1 (type ArgumentNullException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
   at NDepend.TFS.Activities.Helpers.NDependAssembliesResolver..ctor(String ndependInstallPath)
   at lambda_method(Closure , ActivityContext )
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteInResolutionContextT
   at System.Activities.InArgument`1.TryPopulateValue(LocationEnvironment targetEnvironment, ActivityInstance activityInstance, ActivityExecutor executor)
   at System.Activities.ActivityInstance.InternalTryPopulateArgumentValueOrScheduleExpression(RuntimeArgument argument, Int32 nextArgumentIndex, ActivityExecutor executor, IDictionary`2 argumentValueOverrides, Location resultLocation, Boolean isDynamicUpdate)
   at System.Activities.ActivityInstance.ResolveArguments(ActivityExecutor executor, IDictionary`2 argumentValueOverrides, Location resultLocation, Int32 startIndex)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
 The workflow instance has been canceled. (Reason: The activity 'Try to run NDepend process' with ID 20434 threw or propagated an exception while being canceled.)
```

I would like a help to figure out what could be wrong with it.

Comment: the path combine issue looks like an installation problem, could you double check everything is well installed and you follow step by step the doc?  http://www.ndepend.com/docs/tfs-integration-ndepend

Comment: I tried using the deploy tool given, and also I tried to deploy it manually. Both results are the same error.

Comment: I'm testing in TFS 2015 XAML build agente, could it be the issue?

Comment: Yes TFS2015 is not yet supported, we have important plans concerning VSTS support, pls come back to us if you want to be part of the private beta https://ndepend.uservoice.com/forums/226344-ndepend-user-voice/suggestions/8657644-tfs-2015-support